# Restriction of function on a subset

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given is:
Let $M\subseteq { \mathbb{R}  }^{ 2 }$

$M=({ (x,y)\in{ \mathbb{R}  }^{ 2 } }\quad|\quad x\ge 0\quad ,{ -x }^{ 2 }\le y\le { x }^{ 2 })$

Show that the restriction of a function f on M, is a continous function.

I don't understand how to build the function f with the given facts of M.
Thanks for help.

Comment: An arbitrary function on $\Omega\supset M$ doesn't become continuous by restricting it to $M$. You need more information about $f$.

Comment: i dont have more informations given for f. But why would it be false to build a function which coveres all the elements of (x,y) given in the subset and than proof that this function is continous?

Comment: Either you missunderstand the statement or you should check it. There is written "Show that the restriction of a function f ...". This means, that you have to take an arbitrary function $f$ and then its restriction on $M$ is continuous. That is definitely false (Counterexample: $f(x):=1$ if $x>0$ and $f(x):=0$ if $x\leq 0$). Otherwise, if your statement is, that you can construct a continuous function on $M$ is very weak, because you can always construct a continuous function on a set, i.e. $f\equiv 0$.